# Creating shadow image in SWT using ImageData and Gaussian blur

Tags: image, swt, transparency

I'm trying to create programmatically shadow background image in SWT to imitate Material shadows. I've thought that best approach would be create empty transparent Image and use GC to draw black rounded rectangle on it and some Gaussian blur to it.

I'm struggling with transparency on rounded corners of rectangle.

```java
ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
int width = 140;
int height = 140;
// create empty image
Image src = new Image(null, width, height);

// use GC to draw shape
GC gc = new GC(src);
gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
gc.setAlpha(0);
gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, width, height);
gc.setAlpha(255);
gc.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
gc.fillRoundRectangle(20, 20, 100, 100, 22, 22);
gc.dispose();

ImageData imageData = src.getImageData();
imageData.transparentPixel = imageData.getPixel(0, 0);

Image dest = new Image(null, imageData);
saver.data = new ImageData[] {dest.getImageData()};
saver.save("result", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
```

This is the result of running my code:

[image: result]
After adding blur using code from Nebula/Opal project https://github.com/lcaron/opal/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mihalis/opal/utils/SWTGraphicUtil.java I've got something like this:

[image]

How to get rid of white edges and corners, how to add proper transparency to image?

Comment: You can set the `alphaData` array in the `ImageData` to specify the transparency for every pixel

Comment: Is there a way to draw with gc using transparent antialiasing without calculating alpha value for each pixel?

Comment: Not that I know of.